# Firefox Display Issue in Menu Bar at the Top

Tags: bug, top-bar, firefox

Firefox doesn't display the "Stack Exchange Sites", "Recent Inbox Messages" and "Recent Achievements" popup buttons located in the menu bar at the top. The buttons are there - just invisible, though. Hovering over with the mouse will display the tool tips, and they work as expected.

This is Firefox 28 on Windows 7 SP1 (usually, I'm on Safari, and there is no issue).

How do I solve this issue?